# Images from my WP blog doesn't show in other sites

Tags: php, html, css, image, wordpress

why does the images from my site http://allbusters.in doesn't load in other sites like http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com

Here is the JSBin Link to the check. it shows an image from another site which loads perfectly
http://jsbin.com/afahec

Comment: Why are you doing `<img src='http://allbusters.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/facebook_32.png'></img>`? `<img>` has no closing tag.

Comment: it doesn't matter. but why isn't it loading. is it some wp hack?

Comment: Do you have any Wordpress extensions installed... like [Hotlink Prevention](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-automatic-image-hotlink-protection/), for example?

Comment: @wylie no it's a default installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `</img>`.

Remove it and properly close the `<img` tag with a `/>`, then your image appears:

```
<img src='http://www.lantiis.com/images/top.png' />
<img src='http://allbusters.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/facebook_32.png' />
```

[http://jsbin.com/otayuy/](http://jsbin.com/otayuy/edit#preview)

**Why?**

Because non-compliant code is unpredictable.

Comment: @Shahal Tharique:  It's pretty simple.  Compliant code works as expected.  Non-compliant code is non-functional or unpredictable.

Comment: then pls explain why this happening: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/P48Xe/). Here the image is not shown??

Comment: Because your `<a>` was empty (zero size).  [I added some text and this is working.](http://jsfiddle.net/P48Xe/2/)

Comment: wat?? maybe try again or check in different browser?

Comment: @Shahal Tharique:  You should setup a test page someplace else as I think you might be seeing something odd with JSFiddle.  Your [image link](http://allbusters.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/facebook_32.png) is not broken and [I'm not seeing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/BbkBf/5/) you describe.